# Not able to set wallpaper after reboot through ~/.fehbg in .xinitrc in i3 on Arch Linux

Tags: linux, bash, xorg, arch-linux

I'm trying to set my wallpaper using an automated script in `.xinitrc` rather than having to set it after every reboot by myself.

I've used `feh` to set the wallpaper. And then used the generated `.fehbg` script in `.xinitrc`.

The thing is, running `sh .fehbg` after `i3` boots works right and the wallpaper gets set. But adding `sh .fehbg` to the `.xinitrc` just below `exec i3` doesn't seem to do the trick.

Pls help?

Answer (score 0):

Try changeing your `.xinitrc` like this

```
exec i3 &
/bin/sh /absolute/path/to/fehbg &
```